# Mock a Reactive<UISlider>?

Tags: reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I have a ViewModel which has as an input in its initializer

```
init(sliderEvents: Reactive<UISlider>) {
```

In the test i want to do something like

```
slider.send(.touchDownInside)
slider.send(.valueChanged, 5)
slider.send(.valueChanged, 15)
```

To simulate for the VM that the slider was dragged from value 5 to 15 for example

It is unclear to me how RAC has built up the Base: UISlider so i'm confused as to how to make the subclass of UISlider to make this kind of mocking possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach that should work:

```swift
protocol SliderProtocol {
    var valuesSignal: Signal<Float, NoError> { get }
}

extension UISlider: SliderProtocol {
    var valuesSignal: Signal<Float, NoError> {
        return reactive.values
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base: SliderProtocol {
    var values: Signal<Float, NoError> {
        return base.valuesSignal
    }
}

class MockSlider: SliderProtocol {
    let mockValue = MutableProperty<Float>(0)

    var valuesSignal: Signal<Float, NoError> {
        return mockValue.signal
    }
}
```

Your ViewModel should then init with `Reactive<SliderProtocol>` and you could pass the `MockSlider` instance to it. Mocking would be as simple as setting `mockSlider.mockValue.value = 10`.

Comment: Hard to get this to work with the rest of methods that require the slider to be a subclass of UIControl, and the ordinary UISlider in my viewcontroller does not comform to SliderProtocol since its just a UISlider

Answer (score 3):

You could set up the ViewModel to have an `Observer`, `Action` or `MutableProperty` (anything takes inputs) with `Double` type. Then bind the `UISlider` values to that in your ViewController.

So in your ViewController you could have a line like this: `viewModel.sliderValue <~ slider.reactive.mapControlEvents(.valueChanged){ $0.value }` where `sliderValue` could be of type `MutableProperty<Double>`.

In your tests you could then set the values like this: `viewModelToTest.sliderValue.value = 10`

Comment: You are technically correct, but this would be too much work to change in my given code base. So still looking to see if it is possible to just do a mocked subclass.